# Is there a SE site where answers can consist of facts about Internet privacy, censoring the Internet and the consequences thereof to the avg. citizen?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

Is there a place on [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to ask questions that can be responded with facts about things like Internet Privacy, censoring/blocking sites and the consequences of all this for the average citizen?

In my case specifically I would like to get some questions reliably answered on the subject of Internet Privacy, if it's true that e.g. [every EU citizen is currently under surveillance by phone companies](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv7Y0W0xmYQ), who (more likely: which companies) [requested these changes](http://christianengstrom.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/ifpis-child-porn-strategy/), what the pros and cons are of online censorship and similar subjects. All in an as objective and credible (verified by linked sources) way as possible.

I figure I wouldn't be the first to have this idea, so is there a subdomain on SE for subjects like these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try asking your [first question](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv7Y0W0xmYQ) on http://skeptics.stackexchange.com, but *read their FAQ very carefully first!*  (every site FAQ is linked at the top of the respective site).

SE sites are not really the place to go for detailed, painstaking research.  For that, you have to use more primary sources, like libraries, online repositories, and experts.  In short, you'll need to do your own detective work.

Comment: Since SE has "experts" you mean that I need experts for a longer time-span than what is possible on SE sites? Hypothetically, if the 'research needs' are chopped into questions [skeptics.se] I think it could be possible. The reason I believe this, is because I think this topic could easily attract interest beyond just me. Of course, that's up to me to test out. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another site that might address some of your questions is [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) as privacy and censorship are often closely tied up with security.

As with Skeptics, **read the FAQ and previously asked questions** before posting to try and get an idea of the community's interests.