# Do edits to closed questions bump the question?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, faq-update-request, bump

This is an addition to the following question:

> [How to tell if you're making the right edits to your closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149371/193906)

So say you've edited a closed question. Does this bump it on the [Active tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) and/or on some other place visible to [users with enough reputation to leave a reopen-vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)?

My researching skills could only find one topic on this: [Stop an edited deleted answer from bumping the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/stop-an-edited-deleted-answer-from-bumping-the-question)

That question is talking about deleted, not closed, questions but in case the answers are still valid (they're from early 2010), I interpret it as editing a deleted question *does* bump the question. So I would guess that closed questions act the same, but I can't really know for sure, since I don't have high enough rep to test it out myself.

In either case, shouldn't this information be in some [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question?

On [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work), [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question), [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question), [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped) or one of the [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=editing+a+closed+question+%5Bfaq%5D) [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bumping+a+closed+question+%5Bfaq%5D) [FAQ](https://www.google.dk/search?q=bumping+a+closed+question+faq+site:meta.stackoverflow.com) [questions](https://www.google.dk/search?q=edit+bumping+closed+question+faq+site:meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, edits to closed questions bump them.

Here's a question on the meta frontpage right now that was closed last month, but was bumped when Emmett edited it:

[image: Edited question on frontpage]

Given that this is not (yet) a frequently asked question, I don't think that more documentation is necessary beyond what this very question will provide.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it does, but the "priority" of the bump depends on the size of the edit (on Stack Overflow).  If the edit is small or insignificant, you might not see it at the top of the page; it might be six down or twelve down from the top, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Closed questions will sometimes *not* be bumped to the "Interesting" tab of the Stack Overflow homepage, with is the main place where I would consider a "bump" occurring:

> [How does Stack Overflow determine the 'interestingness' of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257921/how-does-stack-overflow-determine-the-interestingness-of-a-question)
>
> - drop closed questions *if* you lack the reputation required to vote for reopening
> - drop questions scoring -4 or lower

Closure often occurs alongside downvotes, so if a question is at -4 or lower no one will see that bump (on the homepage). Sub 3,000 reputation users will never see a closed question bump.

The closed question is, I believe, still bumped to non-homepage areas such as the [active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active) of the main site or tags.